# Perfect GridLayout in android

Tags: android, grid-layout

I want to make a gridlayout like shown below: [image]

and to make so I made my layout like this.

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/glColumns"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvIntro" 
    android:layout_marginRight="43dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:rowCount="6"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvLink1"
     >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlColumn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/button_bg"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_rowSpan="3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPassengerInt"
            style="@style/subInfoInt"
            android:text="@string/passenger_int" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPassengerText"
            style="@style/subInfo"
            android:text="@string/passenger" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlColumn2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_rowSpan="3"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:background="@color/button_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPassengerInts"
            style="@style/subInfoInt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/passenger_int" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPassengerTexts"
            style="@style/subInfo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/passenger" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlColumn3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:background="@color/button_bg"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="3"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPassengerInt2s"
            style="@style/subInfoInt"
            android:text="71,000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPassengerText2s"
            style="@style/subInfo"
            android:text="STRUCTURES" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <!-- ========================================================== -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/rlColumn11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/button_bg"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_rowSpan="3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPassengerInt11"
            style="@style/subInfoInt"
            android:text="@string/passenger_int" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPassengerText1"
            style="@style/subInfo"
            android:text="@string/passenger" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/rlColumn21"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_rowSpan="3"
        android:background="@color/button_bg"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPassengerInts1"
            style="@style/subInfoInt"
            android:text="@string/passenger_int" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPassengerTexts1"
            style="@style/subInfo"
            android:text="@string/passenger" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/rlColumn211"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_rowSpan="3"
        android:background="@color/button_bg"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPassengerIntss1"
            style="@style/subInfoInt"
            android:text="@string/passenger_int" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPassengerTextss1"
            style="@style/subInfo"
            android:text="@string/passenger" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/rlColumn31"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/button_bg"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPassengerInt2s1"
            style="@style/subInfoInt"
            android:text="170" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPassengerText2s1"
            style="@style/subInfo"
            android:text="CITIES" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- ========================================================== -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/rlColumn311"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/button_bg"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPassengerInt2s1s"
            style="@style/subInfoInt"
            android:text="30" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPassengerText2s1s"
            style="@style/subInfo"
            android:text="YEARS EXPERIENCE" />
    </LinearLayout>

</GridLayout>
```

I got the desired output but not perfectly. The errors are mentioned in the picture. The output is like this: [image]

The space are not managed properly and also the row and column span are not proper

How I tried to do this::::

[image]

Comment: In the desired layout picture, I count a maximum of 3 columns and 5 rows. But you have defined 4 columns and 6 rows... why?

Comment: @DerGolem: each block contains 3 columns except the column with 3 block it contains 2 rows. I just made so to manage the structure. I hope you understand

Comment: No, I don't. Because I'm stupid. But I still see a requirement of a 3*5 grid and a definition of a 4*6 one. And it doesn't match. In facts, the result is completely messed up.

Comment: @DerGolem : dan how do you manage 2 rows in 3 cols and 3 rows in 4th col? Can you help me?

Comment: Be patient, in the first drawing you posted (`a gridlayout like shown below`), there's **no 4th column**.

Comment: Also, If every LinearLayout is a column, then I see 8 columns, each of which having 2 "cells" (TextViews). So, if mathemathics is not an opinion, I see an 8*2 design.

Comment: @DerGolem Please look again the question, I have edited how I tried to do this... with 4x6 grid

Comment: Well, this is how to work with a GridLayout (no need to have LinearLayouts bloating the hierarchy): http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_the_Android_GridLayout_in_XML_Layout_Resources

Answer (score 0):

Please check the link.These are the external libraries for creating the custom gridview

> https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridViewDemo
>
> https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid
>
> https://github.com/jacobmoncur/QuiltViewLibrary

Comment: While these links may provide an answer to the OP question, it's better to insert te essential parts of them and some code, since they may be no more available in the future.